# Why morphia @prePersist Annotation not be called when datastore.save()?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Here is the annotationed [@prePersist](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/guides/annotations/#prepersist) method in Class `StageOrmModel.class`:

```
...
private String product;
private List<ProductOrmModel> _product;


@PrePersist
void prePersist(){
    System.out.println("I am in prePersist");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    product = gson.toJson(_product);
    this._product = null;
}
...
```

I would like to serialize the `_product` field to json string before persist the document to mongodb, but when called method `DataStore.save()` by following code snippet:

```
 datastore.save(stageOrmModel)
```

I find not only the `_product` was not set to null( which should be expected  not included in the saved document in this case), but also, the `String product` was not parsed, and the console log `System.out.println("I am in prePersist")` never printed.

Which have I got wrong?

Comment: This looks ok. I'd only annotate the product with `@Transient`, so you don't need to explicitly null it

Comment: @xeraa thanks for advice, that is a better approach. Things come out that I mis-imported the annotation. see the answer post.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured this out:

The thing is I import `javax.persistence.PrePersist` instead of `org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.PrePersist` when the importing was generated by the IDE, I didn't check that.

This is a carelessness mistake, hope this would remind other folks stuck on the same issue.